# How to get a user's input from console and put it into a variable in JS

Tags: javascript

(This is assumed that the user can already see the browser console.)

**Step 1:** User types "Hello" (or something like that, without quotes) into the console.

**Step 2:** Get the user's input (in this case, "Hello".) from the console and put it into a variable called "`user_input`".

I have had a look at:

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/console-in-javascript/

and

https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/obj_console.asp

neither of which document an `input` in the console being a build-in function in JavaScript.

(I currently do not have a JS file created to share, but I hope this enough of an explanation for someone to help me.)

Comment: A little big odd requirement. You want to develop an interactive app in browser console? Why not interactive web page? It is more native for browser.

Answer (score 1):

`prompt` function can be used - not sure what exactly is requirement. If we will start taking input in browser console then what will app do :-)

`let age= prompt("your age"); console.log("Hello, " + age);`